# Do unused outlets consume electricity?

Tags: power-consumption, outlet

My understanding is that unused outlets do not consume electricity, but I came across a [company which sells outlet covers saying](http://www.niagaraconservation.com/energy_conservation/products/miscellaneous/detail?object=5144):

> Saves energy by helping reduce drafts through vacant receptacle
>   outlets

I can't believe they are referring to "air drafts" as this seems such a ludicrous explanation (the outlet holes are so small and they are wired which makes the volume of air going through neglectable) that I'm wondering whether they are referring to electrical drafts which I wouldn't be aware of, hence why I'm seeking confirmation.

**Do unused outlets consume electricity?**

Comment: I think they're referring to air drafts.

Comment: Unused sockets do not consume any power. Oddly enough, when you are building something like a Passive House, this level of heat loss via air drafts might actually be an issue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_house.

Comment: Air drafts is a problem i personally have with outlets! I could feel the cold air draft before I applied some tape over the unused ones in the bedroom... I admit, I didnát believe myself first.

Comment: maybe there should be an Area 51 proposal for a new group, the truth in advertising group; anyone?

Comment: This question is better suited for the home improvement stackexchange site (diy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's only better for home improvement given the answer. The question on its own seems to belong here.

Answer (score 4):

No, unused outlets do not consume electricity, but that doesn't mean you can't lose energy through them.

As already stated in the comments, they are referring to air drafts. The air leaks from all around the socket and past the wall plate, not just through the plug holes.

You're right though, even still, the volume of air passing through is quite small, but is continuous. When companies advertise energy savings from insulation of electrical outlets and light switches it is generally on the order of tens of dollars per year. It could be more depending on the level of insulation in your walls and how many outlets you have. The International Association of Certified Home Inspectors claims that electrical outlets can [account for 2%](http://www.nachi.org/ir-cameras-inspection.htm) of the air leaks in a person's home.

[image]

Flir makes a line of infrared [cameras for detecting such air leaks](http://www.flir.com/thermography/americas/us/view/?id=49418) in homes. Flir further claims that "Heat losses in buildings can account for up to 50% of the total energy consumption and comes from air leakage through chimneys, attics, wall vents and badly sealed windows/doors, etc." Presumably with electrical outlets falling into the etcetera category.

Also the [US Department of Energy](http://energy.gov/public-services/homes/home-weatherization/home-energy-audits) has some useful information on air leaks and other energy vampires.

Comment: Small air leaks may be insignificant in terms of energy, but suppose they carry some bad smell, like cigarette smoke ...

Comment: It's more likely that the cold air coming in is not coming directly from outside. The air inside the walls can cool much more easily because it has access to non-insulated areas. The cool air flows out of the low portions on the wall and warm air from the house is blown into replace it. So, you'd be more likely to get small dead mammal smell rather than cigarette smoke.

Comment: I suspect air leaks via electrical outlets are not an issue in parts of the world where external walls are usually constructed of solid masonry. Or where electrical outlets are internally shuttered (e.g. UK) I'm surprised there is anywhere in the world where thermal air leaks through electrical outlets into/from wall spaces are significant compared to leaks around external doors and windows.